# Regex - Exclude URLs by keywords

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am trying to use StackPath's EdgeRules and their documentation is not very clear or good.
I need to match urls in multiple directories but exclude any URL's that have the extension `m3u8` in it or the word `segment` in it. This is their docs [EdgeRules](https://support.stackpath.com/hc/en-us/articles/360038961332-Getting-Started-with-Custom-EdgeRules#h_c97b7d97-6955-4491-889a-6cf6de2df035)

This works to limit it to 2 directories.

```
/(https://example.com(/(pics|vids)/).*)/
```

But then this doesn't work.

```
/(https://example.com(/(pix|vids)/).+(?!m3u8|segment).*)/
```

I've been trying to use https://regex101.com/ but nothing I try seems to work. I don't even know what kind of regex they use. Hopefully can get some help with this.

Comment: Two issues I can see with your regex: First is that you have unescaped forward slashes, and the second is that you have `.+` before your negative lookahead and `.*` after it. For example, if your URL is `https://example.com/pix/segment`, it can still match because the `.+` consumes `segment`, then the negative lookahead has nothing left to match. To fix this, move the `.+` inside the lookahead (remembering to add brackets around your alternation).

Comment: @ApexPolenta the documentation linked also has unescaped backslashes. Might be a C# thing

Comment: @Panama Jack: Do any of the answers answer your question? If not, please update your question with more details. If yes, please consider accepting one of the answers

Comment: @PeterThoeny Unfortunately not. They don't support negative lookaheads.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this so apologies if its something else wrong...

The negative look aheads need to be side by side, not wrapped in parentheses separated by or (|). I also added a end of line character ($) at the end of `.m3u8`.

`(https://example.com(/(pix|vids)/)(?!.*\.m3u8$)(?!.*segment.*).*)`

See this example:
https://regex101.com/r/reVHWt/1

Comment: Yes in theory this should work. I checked the example and it handles the scenarios but still not working with StackPath's EdgeRules. I have opened a ticket to see what's up.

Answer (score 0):

The EdgeRules docs do not mention the regex flavor they support, and from the examples it is not clear. Also the example `/(^http://example.com(/.*/)+.$)/` shows non-escaped backslashes, indicating this is non-standard regex.

I see no other way than using a negative lookahead to exclude arbitrary patterns. Assuming their regex does support it you can try:

```
/^https://example.com/(pix|vids)/(?!.*\bm3u8\b)(?!.*\bsegment\b).*$/
```

Or with properly escaped special chars:

```
/^https:\/\/example\.com/(pix|vids)/(?!.*\bm3u8\b)(?!.*\bsegment\b).*$/
```

Explanation of regex:

- `^` -- anchor at start of string
- `https:\/\/example\.com/` -- literal `https://example.com/`
- `(pix|vids)` -- literal `pix` or `vids`
- `/` -- slash
- `(?!.*\bm3u8\b)` -- negative lookahead for `m3u8`, anchored on both sides with `\b`
- `(?!.*\bsegment\b)` -- ditto for `segment`
- `.*$` -- any other chars up to end of string